# ConQuest server performs C-MOVE in local network, but not on remote server

Tags: vpn, dicom

I am testing my application against three ConQuest DICOM servers running:
one on localhost, another one on a different computer in the local network, and still another one on a remote machine in the VPN network. The requesting application is present in both local and the VPN networks.

When I am trying to retrieve an image (via C-MOVE) from each of those three instances of ConQuest, both local servers duly respond the request and send me the image. The remote server on VPN, however, responds

"Host 'XXX' did not accept the connection"

and, after a timeout, closes.
I was unable to understand the reason, or, the difference - the corresponding settings in the configuration files on all three machines seem to be identical and correct.

I can successfully verify the VPN ConQuest server. I can also send images to it. But the C-MOVE retrieve does not work.

This is certainly not a firewall problem (I switched out firewall on all computers, and it did not help).

Can the problem have to do with the form of the host name? Do I need to indicate which network I mean, apart from the IP address?

Comment: Could you put the configuration files for each Conquest server?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks A_J and everybody involved. After a while, we gathered enough experience with ConQuest and also with a couple of other PACS in real hospitals. There are principally three things to check:

1. The network parameters (AET, IP, port) of the PACS must be correctly registered with your application (all three you shall learn from the network admin);
2. The PACS must know the same three parameters of your system in its configuration (its physical implementation depending on the system). The port is the number of port on which your C-MOVE listener runs, the IP you can find with ipconfig (ifconfig), and the AET is that you chose. These data you shall tell the network administrator, so that (s)he registers them with the PACS;
3. Configure a firewall inbound rule on the machine where your application runs to allow connection on the port number of your C-MOVE listener.

To our experience, this is all what one needs for all practical purposes.